# How to create a graph with jpgraph with random times on the x-axis

Tags: php, graph, charts, jpgraph

I have data which consists of meter readings from various random times.

I would like to create a (line) graph that shows the variation of the meter readings, however the times are not regular - there might be 3 in one day, or none for a week.

As such, I am not sure how to best create a graph to show this. I can't use the data as it is, because of the randomness of the times - if it's a week between readings, it needs to be represented as a week on the x-axis.

If I give an arbitrary scale (e.g. 1 day per tick), I am not sure how to say "no data at this tick" for where there are gaps. I am also not sure if I can represent a smaller granularity (e.g. if there was one in the morning, one in the afternoon, it would appear in the same place with a 1 day per tick scale I think)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. If you check the LinePlot in the classreference, you see that you can set a second argument for the x axis values. Obviously, the Y and X axis arrays must have the same number of elements. I made some sample code based on the manual. The code is not yet tested, but this is how it should work:

```
function elevation_chart ($ydata, $xdata) {
  require_once('jpgraph/jpgraph.php');
  require_once('jpgraph/jpgraph_line.php');
  $width = 600; $height = 200;
  $graph = new Graph($width,$height);
  $graph->SetScale('intint');
  $graph->title->Set('Elevation profile');
  $graph->xaxis->title->Set('(Distance)');
  $graph->yaxis->title->Set('(Altitude)');
  $lineplot = new LinePlot($ydata, $xdata); //here you have to add $xdata as second argument
  $graph->Add($lineplot);
  $graph->Stroke();
}
```